# Migrate a finished project to Docker

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I have an application created, a Node.js server and a MySQL database.

Initially, for this application, Connection with the database is installed via port 3306, the server starts on 3000.

I created 2 containers for Docker, one for the database, the other for the server.

I assigned ports 3307 and 3001 to listen to both. But I get an error connecting to port 3307. For the experiment I set it to 3306, but it’s clear that there is an error here as the port is already occupied by the initial connection.

**I looked at different answers to stop port 3306 in Connection, will this affect the operation of the application, how will the Docker container replace it? and how should I do this?**

I work with the database via **MySQL Workbench**

**Dockerfile:**

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=18.14.0
ARG DB_HOST=mysql-container
ARG DB_PORT=3306
ARG DB_USER=root
ARG DB_PASSWORD=...
ARG DB_NAME=...


FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

ENV DB_HOST=$DB_HOST
ENV DB_PORT=$DB_PORT
ENV DB_USER=$DB_USER
ENV DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
ENV DB_NAME=$DB_NAME

ENV NODE_ENV production


WORKDIR /...
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=package-lock.json,target=package-lock.json \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci --omit=dev

USER node

COPY ...

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm start
```

**compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  server-container:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-container

  mysql-container:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: DBName
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
```

**error**

```
backend-server-container-1  |
backend-server-container-1  | > backend@1.0.0 start
backend-server-container-1  | > node server.js
backend-server-container-1  |
backend-server-container-1  | Server started 3000
backend-server-container-1  | node:events:491
backend-server-container-1  |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
backend-server-container-1  |       ^
backend-server-container-1  |
backend-server-container-1  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3307
backend-server-container-1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
backend-server-container-1  | Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
backend-server-container-1  |     at Connection._notifyError (/backend/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:252:12)
backend-server-container-1  |     at Connection._handleFatalError (/backend/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:183:10)
backend-server-container-1  |     at Connection._handleNetworkError (/backend/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:196:10)
backend-server-container-1  |     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
backend-server-container-1  |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
backend-server-container-1  |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
backend-server-container-1  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
backend-server-container-1  |   errno: -111,
backend-server-container-1  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
backend-server-container-1  |   syscall: 'connect',
backend-server-container-1  |   address: '127.0.0.1',
backend-server-container-1  |   port: 3307,
backend-server-container-1  |   fatal: true
backend-server-container-1  | }
backend-server-container-1  |
backend-server-container-1  | Node.js v18.14.0
backend-server-container-1  | npm notice
backend-server-container-1  | npm notice New major version of npm available! 9.3.1 -> 10.2.3
backend-server-container-1  | npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.3>
backend-server-container-1  | npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.2.3` to update!
backend-server-container-1  | npm notice
backend-server-container-1 exited with code 1
```

**.env**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=...
DB_NAME=...
```

**DBConnection.js**

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || "localhost",
  user: process.env.DB_USER || "root",
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || pass, //same value like in .env
  database: process.env.DB_NAME || name, //same value like in .env
});

module.exports = db;
```

**any mention about 3307**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

MySQL listens on port 3306, so no matter what host port you map it to, the container side of the mapping should always be 3306.

`- "3307:3307"` should be `- "3307:3306"`

Also note that you only need to map the port on the database container to a host port if you need to access the database from outside the docker network. If the only thing that needs to talk to the database is `server-container` then you don't need to map the port.

`server-container` should always talk to the database on port 3306 as that connection is between containers on the docker network. Those use the container ports.

That means that

```
ARG DB_PORT=3307
```

should be

```
ARG DB_PORT=3306
```

Comment: I also tried that with 3307:3306 but it didn’t work

Comment: Have you changed the `ARG DB_PORT` statement?

Comment: change ```ARG DB_PORT=3306``` but it's still the same err. add in post err message

Comment: The error message says that it's trying to connect to `127.0.0.1:3307` which indicates that it's neither using `DB_HOST` nor `DB_PORT`.

Comment: Okay, could you please tell me what to do to make it work?((

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code that takes the values of `DB_HOST` and `DB_PORT` and makes the database connection?

Comment: Updated it. with connection file and .env

Comment: I'm surprised that it tries to connect on port 3307. You shouldn't have that number anywhere except the docker-compose file anymore. Are you rebuilding the image whenever you make changes? Also, the DB_HOST in the .env file shouldn't be localhost. It should be mysql-container.

Comment: every time before I build containers. I deleted prev try, because sometimes it brings the old version into a new one. Also, I added a pic with a search any mention about 3307 in my workdir

Comment: And the error message still says `127.0.0.1:3307`? That's really weird.

Comment: still ```2023-11-09 20:04:48 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3307```

Comment: Specifically, resetting all internal settings of Docker Windows App now helped with this error. But now the error is the same, but this time not about 3307, but about 3306
 ``` 
errno: -111,
 code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3306,
 fatal: true
```

Comment: `127.0.0.1` indicates that it's using `localhost` and not the DB_HOST value of `mysql-container`. I can't see why it would do that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Change mysql-container internal port to 3306.

```
version: '3'
services:
  server-container:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-container

  mysql-container:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: DBName
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
```